# spring security current user in thread

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-security

hi  i have some problems when use spring security in thread scope

```
System.out.println(((User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getId());
new Thread(() -> System.out.println(((User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal()).getId())).start();
```

this two lines should give me current user id

the first line work as expected

the second line give me NullPointerException as there is no current user it is null value

i found this problem as i want to save many  rows to the song table and it hava  @CreatedBy user  and this will ask for current user in thread and will fail as this will give null value for current user

Comment: Why do you want to have a separate thread for getting the current user? Do it as suggested in first option.

Comment: By default, the Spring Security `Authentication` object is stored in a `ThreadLocal` on a per-`Thread` basis. Therefore, firing a new thread with `new Thread` and then attempting to retrieve the `Authentication` object within that new thread will return `null`. The official Spring Security documentation offers [multiple options](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/concurrency.html) for working in a multi-threaded environment. Review the documentation and choose the strategy suitable to your environment.

Comment: why do you want have separate thread for getting the current user ¿ because I am not calling get current user the createdby annotations calling it and it call it in a thread that I have been created so this done by spring magic

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want spawned threads to inherit `SecurityContext` of the parent thread, you should set `MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL` strategy.

`SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL)`

There was an [issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/6856), when using this with thread pools. This seems to be fixed.

Comment: @JinuPC I've removed broken links and added the code.

Answer (score 9):

you can transfer the SecurityContext from one Thread to another

```
Runnable originalRunnable = new Runnable() {
public void run() {
    // invoke secured service
}
};
SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
DelegatingSecurityContextRunnable wrappedRunnable =
    new DelegatingSecurityContextRunnable(originalRunnable, context);

new Thread(wrappedRunnable).start();
```

See Concurrency Support

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/features/integrations/concurrency.html

Answer (score 3):

If you want all your child threads to inherit `SecurityContextHolder` from the `ThreadLocal` you can use a method annotated with `@PostConstruct` to set it globally. Now your child threads will have access to the same SecurityContextHolder.

```
@PostConstruct
void setGlobalSecurityContext() {
  SecurityContextHolder.setStrategyName(SecurityContextHolder.MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL);
}
```

Cheers